# MySql database connectivity

Tags: mysql

I've written code to insert data in mysql database successfully compiled it on cmd and my database along with table is also ready.
I want to know the further steps so that can understand whether my record has inserted or not in mysql

Comment: Try something like `SELECT * FROM TableNameHere`?

Comment: [Check this tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your code is doing as expected, and there is no error, then the values should be inserted.

Steps to check whether everything is working fine or not:

- Go to your `database` and run this `query`:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM tableName
  ```
- Run the program and `insert` some data.
- Again go to your `database` and run this `query`:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM tableName
  ```

If there are changes appeared according to the data inserted, it means your program is working fine.